# Le particelle sono sempre parte integrante del cognome?

Tags: particles, proper-nouns

In [questa risposta](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/15330/856) su Academia SE, un utente sostiene che se la particella del cognome è di origine nobiliare, questa va scritta maiuscola e ne è parte integrante, **altrimenti** va scritta minuscola e può da questo essere separata.

Ovvero:

1. Di Martino, Emilia
2. Martino, Emilia di

La seconda forma a me pare platealmente sbagliata: non ho mai visto nulla del genere, e credo sia del tutto campata in aria, magari valida in altre lingue, ma mai in italiano.

[Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particella_nobiliare) non lo dice esplicitamente ma prende in considerazione solo il primo caso. Altrove non ho trovato nulla. Dunque?

**Nota bene**: sebbene il discorso originale faccia anche distinzione tra maiuscola e minuscola, ai fini di questa domanda mi interessa **solamente dove piazzare la particella**: che questa sia maiuscola o minuscola può essere interessante ma non è questa la domanda.

Comment: Visto che non è questa la domanda, lo metto in un commento: chi ha scritto in quel modo su Academia.SE ha preso un abbaglio. È proprio il contrario: la minuscola va per i nomi di origine nobiliare. Scrive per esempio Serianni (p. 45): «si oscilla con *de*, *di* che propriamente richiederebbero la *d* minuscola quando introducono un predicato nobiliare: duchi *d'Alba*, Antonio *di Rudini*; la *D* negli altri casi: *Di Maria*, *De Amicis*». La minuscola, per così dire, denota l'appartenenza a una certa casata, mentre la maiuscola indica un cognome “qualsiasi”.

Answer (score 2):

Il *Nuovo manuale di stile* di Roberto Lesina dice a p.134 (anche se dissento sull'uso di maiuscole e minuscole: vedi il mio commento alla domanda):

> In generale, la particelle posta davanti al cognome si scrive con iniziale minuscola quando il cognome è preceduto dal nome personale; con iniziale maiuscola quando il cognome compare da solo:
>   Luca della Robbia, Della Robbia
>   Giuseppe di Stefano, Di Stefano
>   Carlo Alberto dalla Chiesa, Dalla Chiesa
>   [esempi con nomi stranieri]

A parte appunto il discorso discutibile sulle maiuscole, è chiaro che sta dicendo che la particella è parte integrante del cognome (Della Robbia, Di Stefano etc).

Comment: Dissento anch'io sull'uso della maiuscola: se la particella ha la minuscola, questa va mantenuta eccetto che a inizio di periodo. Ma dissento anche sul fatto che la particella sia sempre parte integrante del cognome; non lo è nel caso di particella “nobiliare”. *Luca Cordero di Montezemolo” diventa “Montezemolo”.

Comment: È un inizio, ma preferirei arrivare a qualcuno che ne parli esplicitamente, più che, come in questo caso, parli di una cosa simile e si arrivi alla risposta "per deduzione"…

Comment: @Lohoris: Non so come darti torto.